# Wireless LAN router fingerprinting

Tags: network, attacks, wifi, routing

Does anyone know of a database that lists the range of MAC addresses that are assigned to each particular brand of router?  I would like to use this information for fingerprinting.

I know I can find the manufacturer given the OUI of the MAC address, but I do not know how to find the exact router version.

For example I want to know which MAC OUI belongs to D-Link DIR-645.

Comment: To clarify: are you looking for a list of which MAC addresses were issued to a particular brand of router?

Comment: Exactly, for example I want to know which MAC OUI belong to D-Link DIR-645.

Comment: You should clarify your terminology. A manufacturer (e.g. Buffalo) has brands (e.g. AirStation™), and a brand contains a line of products (e.g. N600, AC 1200). Many router manufacturers don't have clearly distinct brands, and instead just use their company name and a product identifier (e.g. D-Link DIR-645).

Answer (score 1):

I found something, but not quite what I wanted, since there are no assignments between MAC and actual device.

http://www.wardriving-forum.de/statistiken/hersteller/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2088343/Mac-Address-Vendor-List

I remember there was one list like that on a website of small hacking group from germany, but its 3 years ago, I dont remember the address.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Tomáš!  This list is very interesting; thank you for sharing. Unfortunately, it only shows the manufacturer, not the exact version of the router.

Comment: Im not sure if such list could even exist. I think that manufacturer doesnt have to have some MAC range for different type of devices. There are different ways to fingerprint it, like authentication dialog or protocol used for administration(http mostly nowadays, but it could help ocasionally.) The list I didnt found and was mentioning was only list of manufacturers too.

Comment: Well, the manufacturer doesn't have to assign the device ID portion of the MAC address that way, and a sensible manufacturer wouldn't, but I suspect the manufacturing process would be much easier if you gave each production run a serialised list of IDs. (i.e. first device off the line is 00:1b:63:00:00:01, second device is 00:1b:63:00:00:02, and so on.) So a partial version of this list might indeed exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the IEEE public OUI database:

https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html

With the vendor identified you can then zero in on the actual product.